# Rendre footer component all page except 404 pages in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to render the footer component to all pages except the 404 page and request timeout page.
Should I add footer component to all page component individually?

Comment: Add it to all except 404?

Answer (score 1):

*Generally*: No,

- you should avoid repeating code,
- in React you should use [composition](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html) a lot ([break the ui into a component-hierarchy](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html#step-1-break-the-ui-into-a-component-hierarchy)).

*Of course, if your App is very simple or has very few pages, it might be quicker and cleaner to just add the Footer where you want it.*

You should have some kind of "**page layout**" component. (You probably already have one.)

Then you have different options to tell your app if the footer should be shown or not:

#### (A) Seperate layout components

You could use 2 (or 3) different *[specialized](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#specialization)* page layout components.

e.g:

```
// -- main layout --

export const MainPageLayout = (props) => {
    return (<>
        <PageHeader />
        { props.children }
    </>);
};

// -- specialized layouts --

export const NormalPageLayout = (props) => {
    return (<MainPageLayout>
        { props.children }
        <PageFooter />
    </MainPageLayout>);
};

export const ExceptionalPageLayout = (props) => {
    return (<MainPageLayout>
        { props.children }
    </MainPageLayout>);
};

// -- pages --

export const ExamplePage = (props) => {
    return (
        <NormalPageLayout>
            <h1>example page</h1>
            <div>example page content</div>
        </NormalPageLayout>
    );
};

export const Page404 = (props) => {
    return (
        <ExceptionalPageLayout>
            <h1>404</h1>
            <div>not found</div>
        </ExceptionalPageLayout>
    );
};
```

#### (B) use a prop

You could use the same page layout component with e.g. a "page type" property.

Even if this is shorter, I would *generally* **not** recommend this solution, because IMO it is less declarative, but I must admit that I have trouble to reason this.

e.g:

```
// -- layout --

export const MainPageLayout = (props) => {
    return (<>
        <PageHeader />
        { props.children }
        { props.pageType === 'exceptional'
            ? null
            : <PageFooter />
        }
    </>);
};

// -- pages --

export const ExamplePage = (props) => {
    return (
        <MainPageLayout>
            <h1>example page</h1>
            <div>example page content</div>
        </MainPageLayout>
    );
};

export const Page404 = (props) => {
    return (
        <MainPageLayout pageType={ 'exceptional' }>
            <h1>404</h1>
            <div>not found</div>
        </MainPageLayout>
    );
};
```